# Llaves foráneas remotas en SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy comenzando con bases de datos y tengo la duda: ¿se puede tener en una tabla una llave foránea de otra tabla que se encuentra en otro equipo?

Estoy en SQL Server Express. En mi imaginación lo tengo referenciado de esta forma:

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (idCat) REFERENCES [DireccionIP].[WorldShoes].[dbo].[categoria] (idCategoria)
```

¿Saben si me daría resultado?

Comment: Como bien dijo @jachguate no es posible hacer eso. Pero me da curiosidad el saber por qué necesitas algo así..¿por qué sería?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto **no es posible** en ninguna versión disponible a la fecha de SQL Server.

Lo dice claramente la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189049.aspx) (el resaltado es mio).

> - Las restricciones FOREIGN KEY solo pueden hacer referencia a las **tablas de la misma base de datos en el mismo servidor**. La integridad referencial entre bases de datos debe implementarse a través de desencadenadores. Para obtener más información, vea [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189799.aspx).

En otras palabras, no puedes siquiera referenciar una tabla en otra base de datos dentro del mismo servidor, mucho menos una tabla en una base de datos de otro servidor.

Ambas cosas tienen mucha lógica para mi, puesto que de tener integridad referencial entre distintas bases de datos, me vería obligado a hacer backup y/o restore de todas al mismo tiempo, o bien aceptar que podría perder la integridad referencial entre ellas al hacer una operación de restore de cualquiera de las involucradas. Esto rompería totalmente la consistencia que uno espera tener de una base de datos SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Creo que tendré que mover un poco mis tablas entonces... Gracias! :)